# LinkedList in Java and imports

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a linked list in Java, but there is an issue.

I thought that `Link` is in `java.util.Link`,but when I tried to do something like

```
Link nextLink;
```

Eclipse wanted to

```
import sun.awt.image.ImageWatched.Link;
```

I think that this import is different from what I expect and if I import `java.util.Link` it gives error.

Comment: Java usually calls such things Entry or Node. A LinkedList does not consist of Link(s) in any language I know of.

Comment: There's no `Link` class for you to use. You'll need to write it yourself.

Comment: Maybe you want to call to `java.util.LinkedList` instead of `java.util.Link`

Comment: Documentation saves, [java.util.LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Answer (score 2):

use

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LinkTest {
    private LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
}
```